# Django Rest Framework issue in def create method..facing null value in trial end field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

There is a trial end field in subscription model, i want to initialize the field with trial_end_date , 
problem I'm facing now trial_end in subscription model showing null value, How can I extract out the field of trial end field and initialize it? I have attached the def create method looked at that.
I will appreciate your help .

```
  def create(self, validated_data):
    subscriptions_data = validated_data.pop('plan')
    print(subscriptions_data)
    user_memberships = UserMembership.objects.create(**validated_data)
    trial_end = user_memberships.membership.get_trial_period_days()
    trial_end_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(trial_end)
    for subscription_data in subscriptions_data:
        Subscription.objects.create(user_membership=user_memberships, **subscription_data,)

    return user_memberships
```

[Model[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D23qQ.png)

my aim is when in membership model plan contain trial period days , it will add in trial end field of subscription model

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include your code in the question(not an image) and describe what is wrong like error message instead of "not working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you are not passing `trial_end_date`'s value in `Subscription.objects.create(..)`. So you can fix it like this:

```
trial_end = user_memberships.membership.get_trial_period_days()
trial_end_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(trial_end)
for subscription_data in subscriptions_data:
   Subscription.objects.create(trial_end = trial_end_date, user_membership=user_memberships, **subscription_data,)
```